# How to convert a Document-Fragment to string content in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt

I am doing XSLT transformation in the Safari browser using Javascript.

The final output of my transformation is a document-fragment object whose content is as below

```
<chart>
<dataset> .... some data </dataset>
<dataset> .... some data </dataset>
</chart>
```

Basically its the transformed XML output. I need to use this as a string in my Javascript Code.

I am unable to do this using .toString() or whatever. Can somebody please help me here ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `XMLSerializer`:

```
var xmlAsDocument = ... // your XSLT result
var xmlAsString = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString( xmlAsDocument );
```